# Python script gets a 202 response while browser gets a 200 OK

Tags: ajax, python-3.x, selenium, python-requests

I'm trying to automate a checkout process. During one of the phases I have to make a python script get shipping rates from an existing third-party server that **Does not have an API**.

Problem at hand is that when accessed through a browser the third-party server returns a 200 OK response with the information as expected, but when I try to replicate the requests with python the server returns a **202 ACCEPTED with empty body and no *location* in the header**.

Solutions tried and failed:

1. Checking the headers from the browser and imitating them.
2. Checking the cookies sent with the requests and making sure they're sent in the script.
3. Checked the link which I am using.

Additional information:

1. Made the script first using the **Selenium** package and it worked flawlessly but was very slow
2. Ported 99% of the process to the **Requests** library. This is the current state.
3. Browser uses AJAX to make this requests. The callback usually takes 300 ms, python script keeps the connection open until it gets a response.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you imitated the browser headers exactly? I usually use intercepting proxy like burp suite to compare requests made by browser and python-requests to be sure they are the exact match. From your description I can't see another reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: @J91321 I copy the headers 100% alike. I'm starting to guess it's a cookies issue. Perhaps the browser sets cookies using js (?), if so what can I do to get those cookies in python?(The dynamically created ones)

Comment: Well if JS is generating the cookies, the only solution I know is to find the JS code on page and recreate those cookies in python script. Again intercept proxy will show you cookie values sent. Another thing, have you tried PhantomJS with selenium? It should be much faster.

Comment: @J91321 yes I've tried. The original version of the script was done with phantomjs and selenium but it was too slow for the task needed now I'm moving all the code to requests only because it's faster